# Pixelate <body> tag with jQuery without using a <img></img> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

My websites  has some css code that gives it a

> background:url(/img.jpg);

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Pixelating-An-Image-Using-jQuery-Pixelate-Plugin.html

With this script I can pixelate a  tag in my HTML but I need to pixelate the bodys background that has been set with css.

Any Ideas are welcome.

Comment: Either you add the "body" to the pixelate function or, if pixelate can't be done on the body, you need to put a div or img element as your background and call pixelate on that

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I just dint want to use a <IMG element but I think this is the only way to do this. So thanks.